# Chaining animations with callback in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I animate the translation of an `GridView` with multiple `ImageView`s in it with the following chain:

```
gridView.animate().x(10).y(10).setDuration(2000).setListener(
    new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {                
            if(callback != null) {
                callback.run();
            }

            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        }
    }
);
```

The callback is a `Runnable`, defined by the method which calls the chain.

So, here is the problem: For some reason only the y-coordinate gets translated. I tried to remove the `AnimatorListenerAdapter`, and it worked fine.

Why does the Adapter "block" the animation for the x-axis and how do I solve this?

Comment: Does removing y(10) allow animation on the x axis?

Comment: @1owk3y, yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using API level 16's method `ViewPropertyAnimator.withEndAction(Runnable)` at the end of the chain instead of the Listener.

But it would be interesing how to solve the problem in API < 16..